# Cannot resolve symbol, android studio

Tags: java, android, android-support-library, android-appcompat, androidx

It's my first time working with android studio and I get error

> "Cannot resolve symbol AppCompatActivity", and other symbol errors.

[image]

How can I resolve it? I've tried adding things to gradle but nothing workde. Also tried doing "Invalidate caches/restart" but it also didn't work.

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonCall);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:1566"));

                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,
                        Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    return;
                }
                startActivity(callIntent);
            }
        });


    }
}
```

Here are dependencies in gradle file

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7'
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

Comment: [link to picture with errors](https://ibb.co/zFpX4ZM)

Comment: Have you merged your project with Android X ?

Comment: use this import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;  instead of   import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove this two lines from import part and try

```
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
```

Answer (score 1):

As you are using the `AndroidX` dependency

```
androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2
```

And in `MainActivity` you import the

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
```

remove it and import the `androidx  AppCompatActivity` then the error resolved.

**Additional**

Also, please add `com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0` into the `build.gradle`

Comment: I did this and majority of error have gone, but i still get Cannot resolve symbol 'ActivityCompat'

Answer (score 1):

Recently I encountered similar problem - "Cannot resolve symbol AppCompatActivity", although I am using

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
```

Of course I migrated to androidx long time ago. This happened when I tried to debug my application on real device running Android 10. Tried many things: delete .gradle and .idea folders, Invalidate caches, etc.

The only thing that helped was shift to Android Studio 4.2 Canary 12 from 4.0.1.  Although the topic is old, I wanted to support people encountered this error recently.

Comment: This is what solved the problem for me too after invalidating the cache, deleting the .idea folder and importing the project didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot user support lib packages and AndroidX packages together.
So if you have migrated your project to android x you will need to use that library only.

Answer (score 0):

You are using **androidx** then you can **remove** this line in your `build.gradle`

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7'
```

**Change** the import in your class:

```
//Remove these
//import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
//import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;

//Add this
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
```